# Automatic On/Off in QML program (created in Qt)

Tags: c++, qt, automation, qml

I just created manual steering for my application, created in Qt 5.14.2, for raspberry. This is a simple HMI that has few temperature options, that can be set. It also shows real temperature from some simple digital sensor connected to GPIOs. There is also a connected relay that can be turned on and off manually, by clicking a button on the touchscreen.
I managed to create auto refresh seting of temperature display for text on the main panel:

main.cpp:  `item->setProperty("text",QString().setNum(t,'f',1));`
and also in the same file, in `int main`: `item = engine.rootObjects().at(0)->findChild<QQuickItem*>("temp");`

and the main.qml file simple text:

```
Text {
        id: temp
        objectName: "temp"
        x: 25
        y: 167
        width: 190
        height: 105
        color: "#33bc00"
        text: qsTr("10.0")
        font.family: "Arial"
        font.pixelSize: 90
    }
```

And of course also manual steering by adding c++ class (for WiringPi) to the project and then implementing everything in qml:

```
            Button{
                id: buttonRelay1on
                text: '  Relay On '
                palette {
                          button: "#33bc00"
                      }
                onClicked: {
                    output21.pinLow();
                }
            }
```

I have also another text field in qml to display the temperature that is wanted (it can be changed by clicking one of 4 buttons).

QUESTION: What is the simplest way to do the automatic steering of this relay?

I want to create a simple condition:

- if the real temperature is under the temperature displayed in the second text field = turn on the relay, and if it is too high, turn off.

I was trying to do it by creating conditions in main.cpp, but getNumber/getText option doesn't work... only for sending data, as I did for temperature sensor:

`item->setProperty("text",QString().setNum(t,'f',1));`
I also searched for example conditions in qml/qt, but I couldn't find anything reasonable for my issue and my level of knowledge...

Comment: I will try if I understood you correctly. If so let me know so I can put that as an answer. The easy way to it in QML will likely be something like:  `
    readonly property double minTemperature : 35.0

    Button{
       id: buttonRelay1on
       enabled: parseFloat(temp.text) >= minTemperature
    }`

Comment: I will try it asap and will let you know, thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to access QML elements from C ++ but vice versa, in the following trivial example the Sensor is a QObject that maps to a qproperty, and then the conditionals in QML are simpler:

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.15


Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    QtObject{
        id: internals
        property real threshold_temperature: 0
    }

    GridLayout {
        id: grid
        anchors.fill: parent
        columns: 2
        Text { text: "Current Temperature:"; font.bold: true}
        Text { text: Number(sensor.value).toLocaleString(Qt.locale("en_US"), "f", 1)}
        Text { text: "Threshold Temperature:"; font.bold: true}
        Text { text: Number(internals.threshold_temperature).toLocaleString(Qt.locale("en_US"), "f", 1) }
        Text { text: "State:"; font.bold: true}
        Text { text: sensor.value > internals.threshold_temperature ? "Relay On" : "Relay Off"}
    }
    Component.onCompleted: internals.threshold_temperature = 20
}
```

**main.cpp**

```cpp
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>

#include <QTimer>
#include <QRandomGenerator>


class Sensor: public QObject{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(qreal value READ value NOTIFY valueChanged)
public:
    Sensor(QObject *parent=nullptr):QObject(parent), m_value(0)
    {}
    qreal value() const{
        return m_value;
    }
    void updateValue(qreal value){
        m_value = value;
        Q_EMIT valueChanged();
    }
signals:
    void valueChanged();
private:
    qreal m_value;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    Sensor sensor;

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("sensor", &sensor);
    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                     &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
        if (!obj && url == objUrl)
            QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
    }, Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.load(url);

    // emulate temperature
    QTimer timer;
    QObject::connect(&timer, &QTimer::timeout, [&sensor](){
        qreal temperature = QRandomGenerator::global()->bounded(50.0);
        sensor.updateValue(temperature);
    });
    timer.start(1000);

    return app.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

Comment: So after implementing this kind of mechanism I can just set another value of the demanded temperature by clicking another, not related, button? I want to create a couple of set options to display. So if I understand correctly, I must only change this value: `Component.onCompleted: internals.threshold_temperature = 20` but can i change it just by setText option in qml button? - sorry I don't have my workspace for now, but I can still implement it as a code.
Moreover, can I just replace `"Relay On" : "Relay Off"` to, for example:`output9.pinLow() : output9.pinHigh()` and it will work ok, right?